# how use ajax to submit a zend 1.12 form

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I'm using **zend 1.12**,making a **quiz application**. I need to submit form without reloading page using ajax or jquery. Please help me to come out of the problem.

Comment: And what is the question or problem? We can help you answer a specific question but not teaching the whole concept of AJAX and building an API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end the quiz than you can use the

```
$("#form").submit(function() { ... }
```

otherwise you can use click event on button and make ajax request as below example:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "<controller action url here>",    
    success: function(data){

    }   
  });     
});
```

Inside action write down all the submit code logic.

Let me know if any confusions.

Comment: Yes, It is done using the jQuery Library. Let me know what you have used?

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you out.
Can you please accept my answer and do up vote?